# HTML <label> tag/element not recognizing "id" attribute of input element

Tags: html, angular, forms, bootstrap-4, label

I am writing an Angular application which uses ASP.Net Core as a backend, and bootstrap 4 and ngx-bootstrap for styling.

For some reason on all my HTML `<label>` tags (in every component/html file AND even though I have ID and Name attributes that match the "for" attribute of the `<label>` tag), the ID's are not found or recognized. I verified this by running the HTML through chrome dev tools lighthouse audit. Here is a sample of the code:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="fa-pull-left modal-title" id="modalTitle">{{title}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
    <form id="modalForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="swName">Name</label>
            <input id="swName" name="swName" [(ngModel)]="switchman.Name" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eid">EID</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="switchman.Eid" class="form-control" id="eid" name="eid" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="homeOffice">Home Office</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="switchman.HomeOffice" class="form-control" id="homeOffice" name="homeOffice" type="text" />
        </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button (click)="accept()" class="btn btn-success mr-auto" type="button">
        Submit
    </button>
    <button (click)="reject()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>
```

In this section for example:

```
<form id="modalForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="swName">Name</label>
            <input id="swName" name="swName" [(ngModel)]="switchman.Name" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
```

The `<input>` attribute of `id="swName` matches the `for="swName"` attribute of the `<label>` tag, but it isn't being applied at all, as if the `id="swName"` does not exist.

How do I get the label to recongize the ID of the input tag?

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: I would also try without the camel case. That's not HTML standard. try either _ or - for separator.

Comment: Tried without camel case, no difference, will attempt to recreate in stackblitz but it could take me a little while...

Comment: If you inspect the rendered HTML in the dev (F12) tools of the browser, do you see the correct `id`s? Is each `id` unique in the page?

Comment: Yes, the dev tools are showing the label referencing "for" and the "id" of the input matching.

Comment: At the left of the dev tools bar, there is a "Select element" tool (an arrow inside a rectangle), which can also be turned on with `Ctrl+Shift+C` (at least in Chrome and Firefox in Windows). Click on the target element in the page to see that element in the "Elements" or "Inspector" tab of the dev tools window. You can then inspect the HTML markup.

Comment: I checked the markup, the ID and For tags match in each instance.

Comment: Are they unique? If you put the focus in the dev tools window, you can press `Ctrl+F` or `Cmd+F` to search for a specific string in the rendered HTML, like `swName`.

Comment: Yes every element is unique. Not sure why but resharper somehow seems to notice the id not being found, that's how I first noticed the issue. I wonder how resharper can tell? Could resharper be incorrectly reporting? maybe a topic for a different question...

Comment: One way to avoid the problem would be to include the `input` element inside of the `label`. Then the connection would be made, without relying on the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be an issue with Resharper not correctly seeing the ID/For relationship. After further testing using Chrome Dev Tools and Lighthouse, I realized that I did have a few other unrelated ID tags that were truly unresolved.

Once I resolved these, the errors in Lighthouse went away, but my IDE still showed errors. I have submitted a ticket to the JetBrains/ReSharper team. Screenshots attached.

IDE: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.5.1

ReSharper: 2020.1 EAP 5

OS: Win 10

Link to issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-478855

UPDATE: JetBrains/ReSharper were able to recreate the issue and confirm that this is a bug that will be fixed in a future release.

Screens:

[image: Unresolved]

[image: Unresolved2]